# Selecting only rows which are associatied to a row in some other particular table

Tags: mysql, performance, associations

```
table1:
columns: id, name

table2:
columns: id, name

assoc_table1_table2:
columns: id_table1, id_table2
```

I need to select all rows from `table1` where at least one row in `table2` is associated with this row.

What would be an efficient way to do it? Or, more correct in some way?

I'm thinking of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.name
FROM table1 t
JOIN assoc_table1_table2 a ON t.id=a.id_table1;
```

or:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table1 t WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM assoc_table1_table2 a
    WHERE t.id=a.id_table1
);
```

Any ideas on what of the above is generally faster?

(the obvious indices are in place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

I'd recommend using a "WHERE EXISTS" as it will give the optimizer more freedom.

Using "WHERE COUNT(*)" or DISTINCT will force a full table scan to compute.

You only want to know whether at least 1 row exists, for example, on a billion row table. "WHERE EXISTS" can be satisfied as soon as the db finds the first row. On databases with reasonable optimizers, you should find it works well.

Comment: Ha, jast figured this out and edited my question. And you are saying that exist will be superior to join in this case

Comment: Well it depends on your data and your database. The optimizer might very well convert the queries to the same thing. But don't dependon that. A join requires a full scan of at least one side of the join, and often will also full scan (index or table) both sides.